# converting time string from hhmm to hh:mm format in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, optimization

I would like to convert a time string which is in hhmm format to hh:mm format, for e.g

"230" would become "2:30"

"400" would become "4:00"

I did the following

```
var timeString = "200";

var finalString = "" 
            + (((parseInt(timeString)) 
            - ((parseInt(timeString))%100))/100) 
            + ":" 
            + ((parseInt(timeString)%100)? (parseInt(timeString)%100) :"00");
```

It works, but is there a better way?

EDIT:

1) what if "400" should be converted to "04:00"?

Comment: Other than using a library (such as the awesome [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)) your solution is pretty solid. I would, though, convert `timestring` to an integer before calculating the final string, instead of calling `parseInt` every time you need it

Comment: with "better" you are talking about performance, readability or LOC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the moment.js library. Then you can for instance use code like:

```
moment("1230","HHmm").format("HH:mm");
```

Comment: I am trying not to use any js library.

Answer (score 1):

Using String slice() you could do it like this:

```js
const format = function(str) {
  return str.slice(0, -2) + ":" + str.slice(-2);
}

var str = "1230";
console.log(format(str))

var str = "400";
console.log(format(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

so just substring and add your dots, simple ways are the best :

```
var myTimeStr = '400',
   hours = myTimeStr.substring(0, myTimeStr.length-2), 
   mins = myTimeStr.substring(myTimeStr.length-2),
   res = hours + ':' + mins;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten your javascript code without any external lib, just “vanilla-JS”

```
var myTimeStr = '400';
var dt = myTimeStr.match(/(\d{1,2})(\d{2})/);
console.log([dt[1], dt[2]].join(':')); // 4:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var finalString = [timeString.slice(0, timeString.length - 2), ':', timeString.slice(timeString.length - 2)].join('');
```